# Embed SWF wmode opaque Actionscript 3 event Mouse.Down event weird behaviour

Tags: html, actionscript-3, mouseevent, flash-cs5

I have an embed swf where variable wmode has the value "opaque". I need to keep with value "opaque" because i have to control the swf layer against the others html elements, however wmode "opaque" causes a weird behaviour on MouseDown event.

If the cursor is hidden (by Mouse.hide()) and you try to press the left mouse button, the cursor will show up until you release the left button or move the mouse.

If you've changed your cursor to another one (by MouseCursor) the same bug will happen (i.e the cursor will turn on arrow mode).
First I was thinking that it was my application bug, then i made a quick example and the error persisted.

When I change the wmode value to "window", the error don't happen, but I have to keep with wmode "opaque".

My example:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
Mouse.hide();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,example);

function example(e:MouseEvent){
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "Hello World!");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="flashContent">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
        width="100%"
        height="610px"
        id="pl_main">
        <param name="movie" value="teste_moude_down.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <embed src="teste_mouse_down.swf" 
            width="100%" 
            height="610px"
            autostart="true"
            quality="high"
            bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="opaque"
            name="pl_main"
            id="pl_main"
            allowScriptAccess="always"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: I've experienced similar mouse weirdness when using different wmode settings. I vaguely recall having issues with context menus and mouse icons. Sorry that I can't be of much help, but if it's any consolation it seems like it's not you and it's just a buggy area :(

Comment: The bug only happens on Chrome, I found a bug report in Chromium (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39436#makechanges) and it seems the bug occurs to other people too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed swf, and you decide a lot of problems with embeding.